# Non-accumulation points are spaced apart

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a separable metric space and $A\subset X$ is an infinite uncountable set.  $x \in X$ is said to be the accumulation point of $A$ if $\forall \varepsilon>0$ $B(x, \varepsilon) \cap A \backslash\{x\} \neq \emptyset$.  Let's define $A_0=\{x \in A \mid\exists \epsilon>0, B(x, \epsilon) \cap A=\{x\}\}$.  Prove that, for all $x,y \in A_0$ with $x\not=y$, there exist $\epsilon_x,\epsilon_y>0$ such that
$$
 B\left(x, \epsilon_x\right) \cap B\left(y, \epsilon_y\right)=\emptyset
 $$

I tried to use the contradiction to be able to use the argument that $x,y\in A_0$ but I can't get the intersection to be empty.  Since $x\not= y$ I thought of using this idea to show that the balls are disjoint, since the balls associated to these points give the same point when they intersect $A$, but it is in particular $A$ that does not allow me to work directly with the balls, so I don't know how to continue.  I would appreciate some help.

Comment: For each accumulation point, take an $\epsilon$ given by the definition, and halve it.

Comment: @DavidHartley but I need to work with the non-accumulation points, and you are telling me to use the accumulation points. In any case, following what you suggest, I cannot conclude what is requested.

Comment: Sorry, I meant non-accumulation point. I.e for each $x \in A_0$ choose an $\epsilon_x$ such that $B(x, 2\epsilon_x) \cap A=\{x\}$.

Comment: @DavidHartley of course, following these steps, my idea is to follow through contradiction. Taking $z\in B(x,\epsilon_x)\cap B(y,\epsilon)$ I have that $z\in B(x,2\epsilon_x)$ and $z\in B(y,2\epsilon_y)$, so if I manage to show that $z\in A$, I will have the contradiction that I expect, however this is where I get stuck. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Isn't $\varepsilon_x = \varepsilon_y = \frac{1}{4}d(x,y)$ always working independently of $x,y$ being in $A_0$ or not? I suspect that there is a typo and that $\varepsilon_x$ must be found independently of any $y\in A_0$.

Comment: @Didier: Now that you mention it, obtaining disjoint open balls is rather trivial -- every metric space is a $T_2$ space, and open balls form a basis for the topology. I wonder whether my carefully written and proofread proof is simply a horrendously complicated way of proving something obvious with no redeeming aspects, or whether it can be tweaked to prove what the OP intended. I'm not all that interested in investigating this now, but if the OP posts a corrected statement of what is intended, I'll look into this at a later time (probably tomorrow, if a correction is made before then).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on the hint given by @David Hartley:

Let $x$ and $y$ be **different** elements of $A_0.$ Choose $\epsilon'_x > 0$ and $\epsilon'_y > 0$ so that $B(x, \epsilon'_x) \cap A=\{x\}$ and $B(y, \epsilon'_y) \cap A=\{y\}.$ Let $\epsilon_x = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon'_x$ and $\epsilon_y = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon'_y.$ To show that $B\left(x, \epsilon_x\right) \cap B\left(y, \epsilon_y\right)=\emptyset,$ assume for a later contradiction that there exists $z$ such that $z \in B\left(x, \epsilon_x\right) \cap B\left(y, \epsilon_y\right).$ Since $z \in B\left(x, \epsilon_x\right),$ we have $d(x,z) < \epsilon_x = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon'_x.$ Since $z \in B\left(y, \epsilon_y\right),$ we have $d(z,y) < \epsilon_y = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon'_y.$

Using the triangle inequality, we have

$$d(x,y) \;\; \leq \;\; d(x,z) \; + \; d(z,y) \;\; < \;\; \frac{1}{2}\epsilon'_x \; + \; \frac{1}{2}\epsilon'_y$$

At this point it will help to introduce the positive number $\max \{\epsilon'_x, \, \epsilon'_y \},$ which is greater than or equal to each of $\epsilon'_x$ and $\epsilon'_y.$

From the last inequality and $\;\epsilon'_x \leq \max \{\epsilon'_x, \, \epsilon'_y \}\;$ and $\;\epsilon'_y \leq \max \{\epsilon'_x, \, \epsilon'_y \},\;$ we have

$$ d(x,y) \;\; < \;\; \frac{1}{2}\epsilon'_x \; + \; \frac{1}{2}\epsilon'_y \;\; \leq \;\; \frac{1}{2}\max\{\epsilon'_x,\,\epsilon'_y\} \; + \; \frac{1}{2}\max \{\epsilon'_x,\,\epsilon'_y \} \;\; = \;\; \max\{\epsilon'_x,\,\epsilon'_y\}$$

We now consider two exhaustive cases, which however are not necessarily distinct (because $\epsilon'_x = \epsilon'_y$ is possible).

**Case 1:** $\;\;\underline{\max\{\epsilon'_x,\,\epsilon'_y\} = \epsilon'_x.}$ From $d(x,y) < \max\{\epsilon'_x,\,\epsilon'_y\}$ we have $d(x,y) < \epsilon'_x,$ and hence since we also have $y \in A_0 \subseteq A,$ it follows that $y \in B(x,\epsilon'_x) \cap A.$ However, this contradicts $x \neq y$ and $B(x, \epsilon'_x) \cap A=\{x\}.$

**Case 2:** $\;\;\underline{\max\{\epsilon'_x,\,\epsilon'_y\} = \epsilon'_y.}$ From $d(x,y) < \max\{\epsilon'_x,\,\epsilon'_y\}$ we have $d(x,y) < \epsilon'_y,$ and hence since we also have $x \in A_0 \subseteq A,$ it follows that $x \in B(y,\epsilon'_y) \cap A.$ However, this contradicts $x \neq y$ and $B(y, \epsilon'_y) \cap A=\{y\}.$

**After thought:** I don't seem to have used the hypotheses that $X$ is separable or that $A$ is uncountable.

Comment: Thank you very much! Another question i have is how can i check that $A_0$ is countable.  Any hint?

Comment: Consider the After Thought in Dave Renfro's answer.